# Error: Argument 'ModalDemoCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, python, html, angularjs, django

Hi I am getting the above error when I used angularJS in my project. I am using django frame work for my whole project. so I dont have any extra js file for my project. The following is my codes.

JS:

```
{{ ngapp }}.controller("ModalDemoCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $cookies, $resource, $log, $modal) {


                                $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

                                $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

                                $scope.open = function (size) {

                                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                                animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                                templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                                controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                                size: size,
                                resolve: {
                                items: function () {
                                return $scope.items;
                                }
                                }
                                });

                                modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
                                $scope.selected = selectedItem;
                                }, function () {
                                $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
                                });
                                };

                                $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
                                $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
                                };

                                });

                                // Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
                                // It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

                                {{ngapp}}.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

                                $scope.items = items;
                                $scope.selected = {
                                item: $scope.items[0]
                                };

                                $scope.ok = function () {
                                $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
                                };

                                $scope.cancel = function () {
                                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                                };
                                });
```

and part of my html(its so long thats why):

```
<div class="well" ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="enable.html">
    </script>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="open('lg')">blahh</button>&nbsp </div>
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong in here. I have trying to figure out for a long time already. N idea how to deal with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure what {{ngapp}} is.  Is that django stuff?

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies should be inferred but maybe try injecting the $scope and others like so.

```
controller("ModalDemoCtrl", ['$scope','$http','$cookies', '$resource', '$log', '$modal', function ($scope, $http, $cookies,   $resource, $log, $modal) { 
...
}]);
```